# Running Perforce Trigger executable from depot

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to run an executable as a perforce trigger from the depot, but oh boy does it NOT want to work ...

Executable is tested locally and works, is submitted into P4 depot into //depot/triggers

Create the trigger as
SubmitNotify change-commit //depot/... "%//depot/triggers/myapp.exe#3%"

Test the submission, and I get a whole bunch of garbage that looks like it's failing to create a temp file somewhere ...
'SubmitNotify' validation failed: /p4/1/tmp/tmp.14296.139872835644864.564.exe: 1: /p4/1/tmp/tmp.14296.139872835644864.564.exe: MZÿÿ¸@º´: not found
/p4/1/tmp/tmp.14296.139872835644864.564.exe: 1: /p4/1/tmp/tmp.14296.139872835644864.564.exe: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Any help much appreciated as it's driving me nuts ...

Comment: The error message references Unix-style paths, but your trigger has an `.exe` filename.  Are you testing a compiled binary locally on Windows and then trying to run it on a Unix server by any chance?

Comment: You, sir\madam, win the big prize! That's exactly what it was, our server was shifted over to a Linux install a couple of months ago!

Answer (score 1):

As Samwise said, I was trying to run a Windows exe on Linux install. D'oh!